# How to save image into folder using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, file

I am working on a HTML project. I need to save an image to my project folder which is selected by using file upload. How can I write this code using only jquery. I want to save the image into the "Resources" folder in my project.

Comment: You cannot do that. File upload control will have file in the POST request, and you need to handle it on server side. Another point that JQuery is client side javascript library.

Comment: You cannot download files to particular folder using Browser only/ using JavaScript. 

You need a server to handle this and save files to a particular file.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#File")[0].files[0]
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<input id="File" type="file">

</body>
</html>
```

Client side only save the img name and path

OR

You send the img details to serverside . Then process the imagedata after retun the string value. Then to save the image